# ParseUser SignUpAsync method not failing when user exists in DB

Tags: parse-platform, xamarin, registration

This is my first time using Parse and after reading a bunch of documentation I have started coding something using it.

Everything has been smooth but I now have a little problem/doubt. I read somewhere that SygnUpAsync should throw an exception when an existing user tries to register again through the SignUpAsync call. For me this is not happening and no exception is thrown. It seems in previous versions this method was named SignUpInBackground and same rules applied.

This is the code I'm using on Xamarin.Android:

```
        EditText passwordEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etPassword);
        EditText userEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etUserName);
        EditText emailEditText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etUserEmail);

        string password = passwordEditText.Text;
        string userName = userEditText.Text;
        string email = emailEditText.Text;

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(password) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(email))
        {
            try
            {
                ParseUser user = new ParseUser()
                {
                    Username = userName,
                    Password = password,
                    Email= email

                };

                await user.SignUpAsync();
                System.Console.WriteLine("User " + ParseUser.CurrentUser.Username + " has been registered.");
            }
            catch (ParseException ex)
            {
                //This is never called
                _ShowAlertDialog("The given user was registed previously. " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //This is never called
                _ShowAlertDialog("Error: " + ex.Message);
            }
        }
        else
            _ShowAlertDialog("Some fields contain invalid values. Please, fix them and retry.");
    }
```

Could anybody clarify this?

Cheers.